# Javascript code not executiing in order

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, bpopup

I have 2 divs which are currently displayed on the screen as popups,

```
<div id="div1">div1 </div>
```

and  `<div id="div2"> div2 </div>`

div2 currently has the focus, and its z-index is greater than div1. While div2 has the focus, i need to do the following in the exact order:

load div1 with a jsp page
close div2 (when div2 is closed, focus returns to div1, and it should automatically be dynamically loaded.

Heres the code i have so far:

```
$("#div1").load("div1data.jsp", {parameter: PARAMETER},function(){
                      $("#div2").bPopup().close();  //close the popup instance that is div2
                      $("#div2").remove();  //remove from dom
            });
 });
```

The problem is that div2 is closing, and when focus returns back to div1, it's not loaded. So it's closing the div2 popup before loading the jsp file to div1, so the changes are not dynamically reflected. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can't you just add a `$("#div1").focus();` after removing div2?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to build a proper window manager instead of mucking about trying to write tangled code.

Keep a list of open windows. Implement an onfocus and onblur event for the windows. When one window closes chose a new window to focus.